# Append a new div element on each button click in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm coding a notetaking app and using new divs as notes.
I created a div customized with CSS which I would use as a template whenever I want to create a new note.
However, I can only add a single one when I click the button.

```js
addNote() {
  noteBank.appendChild(newNote);
}

let noteBank = document.querySelector(".note_bank")

newNote = document.createElement("div");
newNote.classList.add("new_note")

let addNew = document.querySelector(".add_note")
addNew.addEventListener('click', () => {
  notebook.addNote()
  notebook.styleNote()
})
```

I used cloneNode(true) and it worked, but it doesn't duplicate event listeners so I couldn't move on with that.
I want a way to add new elements with each button click, while still giving each new element an event listener

Comment: Use event delegation for the event listeners.

Comment: Or make a clone of the node, and do `clone.addEventListener()`

Comment: You need to create `newNote` inside the event listener function. You're just creating one div when the application starts.

Comment: I tried that, but I had an issue where any adding a new child to the div only affected the most recently created "newNote"

Comment: What does your HTML look like? It would be best to have a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

```js
let noteBank = document.querySelector(".note_bank");

let addNew = document.querySelector(".add_note");
addNew.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let newNote = document.createElement("div");
  newNote.classList.add("new_note");
  newNote.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.classList.add('marked_for_deletion');
    this.remove();
  });

  let noteText = document.createElement("p");
  noteText.textContent = "New note text";
  newNote.appendChild(noteText);

  noteBank.appendChild(newNote);
});
```

```html
<div class="note_bank"></div>
<button class="add_note">Add Note</button>
```

Comment: It would help if you put some content into the new note so there's something to click.

Comment: I tried that, but I had an issue where any adding a new child to the div only affected the most recently created "newNote"

Comment: But I want to replace the 'console.log("Note clicked!")' with 'this.classList.add("')' .
I want to add a class to the div I click so that it deletes that div but it returns an error message

Comment: @TeDi i updated the code, this will add a class of "marked_for_deletion" to the clicked div and remove it from the DOM

Comment: Why would you add a class to remove that element? In case that there is no MutationObserver or similar, this will be useless.